# Cannot import libgdal with python django

Tags: python, django, gis, postgis

I get this error with Django:

```
>>> import django.contrib.gis.gdal
>>> print django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal.gdal_full_version()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'libgdal'
```

but I have this:

```
$ locate libgdal

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.pyc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.pyo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Importing a package in python does not necessarily automatically import any subpackages/modules under it. When you do `import django.contrib.gis.gdal`, that runs `__init__.py` in the gdal directory; it's up to that file whether it then does `import libgdal` in order for that to become available through `gdal`. In this particular case, `gdal` imports (among others) `gdal_full_version` function  from `libgdal` into itself, but not `libgdal` as a whole, so you can just do:

```
>>> import django.contrib.gis.gdal
>>> print django.contrib.gis.gdal.gdal_full_version()
GDAL 1.6.3, released 2009/11/19
```

Or to be explicit as to where the function is actually defined, you could do:

```
>>> import django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal
>>> print django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal.gdal_full_version()
GDAL 1.6.3, released 2009/11/19
```